# Proving that table totals can always be preserved with ceiling and floor

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, number-theory

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline 11.998& 9.083 & 2.919 & &24 \\ \hline 12.983&10.872&3.145&&27\\ \hline 1.019&2.045&0.936&&4\\ \hline & & &\\26&22&7&&55& \hline \end{array}$

turns into:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} \hline 11& 10 & 3 & &24 \\ \hline 13&10&4&&27\\ \hline 2&2&0&&4\\ \hline & & &\\26&22&7&&55& \hline \end{array}$

We assume that for every row and column, the decimal representations will always sum to be a whole number, and correspondingly the row and column sums will always be whole numbers. The task is to prove that a new table can be constructed that is the ceiling and floor of all numbers in the table such that all row and column sums stay the same.

I'm not really sure how to prove this. I was thinking we could strip the decimal representation from each row and column and keep a "decimal total" value for each row and column, but I don't know how to show that we can modify with only ceiling and floor to keep row and column totals the same. I can somewhat see why it would be true for a small table (e.g. $2 \times 2$), but extending it to a table of $n \times n$ does not seem so intuitive (even though I can see that it will be true, I'm not sure how to actually prove it).

Comment: Can you floor everything and work upwards?

Comment: @MarkBennet That was what I'd initially thought of. The "work upwards" part is what's giving me difficulty, because when we add to a row, the column also changes, and it doesn't seem so clear what arrangement will make everything sum up accordingly.

Comment: Can we make a statement about how many times we use ceiling vs floor per line/column? My first thought was that they must be equal which is obviously not true.

Comment: @flawr my thought was to floor everything and keep the decimal total for each row and each column in hand. Then, when we take the ceiling of a number, we minus $1$ from the corresponding row and column decimal total we have for that number's row and column. Ultimately, we should end up with a table that has a $0$ decimal total for every row and column that also keeps the sums of the rows and columns the same as the original table. Proving that this is possible is where I'm having trouble.

Comment: Note that it suffices to do the case where all the entries are between zero and one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson That's an interesting observation I hadn't thought of. Do we just ceiling an entry that has both its row and column sum equal to 1?

Comment: I don't know.${}$

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think that allocating ones and zeros to a grid might be formally hard (given row and column totals), but your observation suggests proving the non-existence of a minimal counterexample, which may be possible.

Comment: @JennParker Reduce every entry by its integer part.

Comment: Another observation: We now can say we have an $n\times n$ grid of numbers in $[0,1]$ (or $[0,1)$ if that helps). When filling the grid, we have obviously $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ degrees of freedom (= independent grid cells).

Comment: @MarkBennet I've done that. I just don't know how to *prove* that the problem can now be solved. It feels like there's been a reduction in the hardness of the problem when all numbers are between $0$ and $1$, but I don't know how to use that to my advantage.